# How to merge a few DataFrames in one loop in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, merge

I have DataFrame and function in Python Pandas like below:

data frame:

```
VALUES_RNG |COL_D   | PRICE
-----------|--------|----------
500-600    | XXX    | 580
200-300    | ABC    | 240
200-300    | ABC    | 230
500-600    | GG     | 555
...        | ...    | ...
```

**VALUES_RNG has the following values: 200-300, 500-600**

function:

```
def xx(df):
    for el in df.VALUES_RNG.unique().tolist():
        data = df[(df["VAL_RNG"] == f"{el}") & (df["COL_D"]!="XXX")][["PRICE"]]
        x1 = data['PRICE'].describe(percentiles = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]).to_frame()
```

And above function create DataFrames with percentiles, but I would like to:

- merge IN LOOP IN FUNCTION all created by this function DataFrames,
- in names of output DataFrame I need: column "PRICE" + values from "VALUES_RNG"

So as a result i need something like below:

| idx | PRICE_200_300 | PRICE_500_600 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| count | 111.12 | 875 |
| mean | 218.83 | 560 |
| std | 20.83 | 102 |
| min | 202.83 | 501.20 |
| 10% | 208.11 | 520.18 |
| 20% | 250.87 | 550.01 |
| 30% | 280.43 | 560.87 |
| max | 299.13 | 597.12 |

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Comment: How can `COL_D` ever match a value in `VALUES_RNG`: `df["COL_D"] == f"{el}"`? The sample data show they are very different

Comment: Code Different, yes your are right, my mistake, I am sorry - I edited question, now it is ok :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use `pivot`. here is just an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'VALUES_RNG': ['500-600', '200-300', '200-300', '500-600', ],
    'COL_D': ['XXX', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'GG', ],
    'PRICE': [580, 240, 230, 555, ],
})

df = df.pivot(values=['PRICE'], columns=['VALUES_RNG'])
print(df.describe())  # result:

                 PRICE           
VALUES_RNG     200-300    500-600
count         2.000000    2.00000
mean        235.000000  567.50000
std           7.071068   17.67767
min         230.000000  555.00000
25%         232.500000  561.25000
50%         235.000000  567.50000
75%         237.500000  573.75000
max         240.000000  580.00000
```

Comment: But I need to to that in for loop, moreover in output I need names of columns like I presened in question word "PRICE" + value from VALUES_RNG, do you have idea how to do that in for loop ?

Comment: @unbik could you explain why do you need a loop? about column names... I don't understand the problem. Just use [rename(columns={blablabla})](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html#pandas-dataframe-rename)

Comment: Danila, when I use your code I have error: KeyError: 'Level VALUES_RNG not found', what can I do ?

Comment: @unbik sorry my friend. [I don't know](https://onecompiler.com/python/3ykdqxqvy) what are you doing)))

Comment: It is really, strange, because copy paste code from your example on example DF generate above error, is it working for you ? did you tried to use you code ?

Comment: @unbik how could I not try if I sent you a link to the working example? )

Comment: I write about df = df.pivot(values=['PRICE'], columns=['VALUES_RNG']) because this line generate error: KeyError: 'Level VALUES_RNG not found',

Comment: maybe in loop you are some idea ?

Comment: @unbik 90% your problems related to `env`(pandas/python version). I won't debug your `env`. I just shared to you approach. You can do it using 1 line of code. And I'm sure you can find how to adaptate approach to your `env`. JFYI: you still didn't answered why do you need a loop and more lines of code.

Comment: whene I change pivto to pivot_table in your code - it works, but it makes wrong calculation, maybe you are albe to do that in loop as i think about that in question ? I think it could be easier

Comment: @unbik oh, come on...  maybe you need just remove `XXX` records before `pivot_table()`(example: `df = df[df['COL_D'] != 'XXX']`). maybe something else.

Comment: try to use pivot_table instead of pivot in your code and you will see that in generate the same number in each percentiles and it is wrong

Comment: @unbik sorry my friend )  look at your input(`df` with 4 records), expected output and answer why it's not possible  do you have problems with data and calculation or with `df` transformation? I will not solve all your tiny technical details in 1 question.

Comment: Tranbi, pleae copy paste all code of Danila, with example DataFrame and you will see error, so it is the reason why this answer was downvoted :/

Comment: does anoone knows how to solve this using for loop?

Comment: @unbik the solution works fine for me and on the link Danila provided. Check your pandas version and your dataframe. For loops are highly inefficient when using pandas

Comment: Tranbi, which version of pandas do you have that "pivot" works for you ? :)

Comment: Moreover, event if it is unefficient, are you able to create loop as I started create in question ?

Comment: Why don't you run `pip install -U pandas` to get to the newest version? I don't know why you insist on using loops but it seems you did so in your question. just concatenate the DataFrames along the column axis using `pd.concat`.

Comment: Tranbi could you present your idea in loop ?